# Migrating my .NET Core RC1 app to Core RTM and Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2 no longer contains "ServiceAccountCredential". How do I fix this?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

Hey so in my RC1 app I have a Google Service which uses a `ServiceAccountCredential` which initializes the email and the scopes from the certificate. However, when I try to run the same code in the RTM version of Core, `ServiceAccountCredential` does not exist in `Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2`. Only `ServiceCredential`.

Is this a known issue? Could really use some help. Thanks.

Edit:

Here's a snippet of my project.json for the RTM

```
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
"Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1": "1.13.1.447",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0",
"AutoMapper": "5.0.0"
```

Comment: So you have no "dotnet restore" (nuget package) problems but you do see signature changes between RC1 and RTM in the version of your google API package? What google api package are you using? You didn't report your project.json.

Comment: Hey sorry about that, I should have clarified more in the OP. In the RTM I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0", and in the RC1 version I'm using "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-rc1-final". I tried using the same version I used in RC1 in the RTM, but still the same issue. I also updated my OP with my project.json

Comment: @AnthonyMascia are you asking the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591557/google-oauth2-serviceaccountcredential-does-not-exist-when-using-asp-net-core)?

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

> Is this a known issue?

Yes, [this is a known issue.](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/695). As of today the issue remains open.

To paraphrase, `ServiceAccountCredential` does not yet have a cross-platform implementation. The Google APIs Client for .NET does not yet work in a .NET Core Application.

## Something to Try

What you *could* try is to clone and build the `netcore` branch of [Google's .NET Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client). Then use the build results in your application.

```
git clone https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client.git
git checkout netcore
```