# Google OAuth2 "ServiceAccountCredential" does not exist when using ASP.NET Core (RTM)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, google-authentication, service-accounts

I had a ServiceAccount hookup in my .NET Core RC1 app that worked fine. However now, "ServiceAccountCredential" doesn't exist in "Google.APIs.Auth.OAuth2" anymore. The whole library seems to be missing a ton of classes in the RTM version of Core.

Here are the related packages in my project.json

```
"Google.Apis.Core": "1.14.0",
"Google.Apis.Auth": "1.14.0",
"Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2": "1.14.0.540"
```

I even tried using the RC1 packages, but I keep getting the same thing. Is it simply because Google Auth isn't fully supported in Core yet?

Comment: Did you tried using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google` package? https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google for source. https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html is an example for facebook. Google is similarly, but not yet there in the docs. Check the GitHub repository from above

Comment: Direct link to the sample :P https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/1.0.0/samples/SocialSample/Startup.cs#L107-L121

Comment: @Tseng that is about authentication via Google. OP wants to use Google API's to access Google services using a service account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google API's indeed do **not** fully support .NET Core yet: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/695.

In fact the `ServiceAccountCredential` is problematic (as I mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/695#issuecomment-235280413)) since it calls Windows-specific API's to parse the certificate. It has to be implemented cross-platform first to fully support .NET Core (.NET Standard actually).

Comment: And that was exactly the confirmation I was searching for. I had a strong feeling it just wasn't/isn't supported. Thanks for the link - I can now look in to alternatives.